# Prints ten characters per line from 1 to Z using def

Tags: python

```
import string

def printChars(ch1,ch2,char_line):
    NUMBER_PER_LINE = char_line
    count = 1

    for i in range(NUMBER_PER_LINE):
        i = 0

    print(string.digits)
    print(string.ascii_uppercase)
    if i <= char_line:
        print('\n')
    elif i >= NUMBER_PER_LINE:
        return

  # AFTER LOOPING AND DONE  
    print(format(number, "5d"), end = '')
    if count % NUMBER_PER_LINE == 0:
            print()
printChars('1', 'z', 10)
```

And my result is

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

This is the problem

> Write a function that prints characters using the following header:
>   def printChars(ch1, ch2, numberPerLine): This function prints the
>   characters between ch1 and ch2 with the specified numbers per line. 
>   Write a test program that prints ten characters per line from 1 to Z.

My result should be

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: You have an infinite loop under `while numer < 90`, as `number` never changes, and starts at 48.

Comment: why am i getting bad reviews

Answer (score 0):

You start in this loop

```
    number = 48

    digit = True
    while number  48:
            digit = True
            count += 1
        if number  48:
            digit = False
```

with **number = 48** in **none** of the "ifs" you validate **number == 48**, so python never changes the value of number and thus **it can never exit the loop**